# AngularJs watch function per scope of per model member

Tags: angularjs

This is regarding the usage of $watch by AngularJs.

I have below controller function.

```
 function MyController($scope) {
      $scope.foo1 = 1;
      $scope.bar1 = { mem1: 2 };
      $scope.bar2 = { mem2: "value2", mem3 = "value3"};
    }
```

and my view as below

```
<html>
<body>
  <div> {{ foo1 }}</div>
  <div> {{ bar1.mem1 }}</div>
  <div> {{ bar2.mem2 }}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please tell me that how many watchers will be created by AngularJs for above controller function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No watchers were created as a result of the controller code. Watchers are created by `$scope.$watch`or by directives (`ng-click`, `ng-change`, `ng-bind`, etc.). Specifically in your case, when the template is presented, it is the one that creates watches for each angular expressions - the ones inside double curly brackets {{ }}.

Comment: In your view, there is 3 {{ }} (ng-bind). So you will have 3 watchers.

Comment: Thanks Sebastien!!. Just one quick doubt, suppose my model is so complex and it has thousands of members and all members are referenced in views. so in that case thousands of watchers will be created ? If yes, isn't is Angular making the model so heavy?

Comment: The watchers number are not directly linked to your model. It's linked to what your are doing in your view. Basically, more you want to display data (except for bind-once) more your watchers number will be hight

Answer (score 1):

You can install google chrome extension (for example https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-watchers/nlmjblobloedpmkmmckeehnbfalnjnjk) - it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

3 watchers will be created (for foo1, bar1 and bar2)